# shared v-model value between child and parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component which shares `v-model` same as parent component. The code is like below:

```js
Vue.component('greeting', {
  template: '<input type="text" :name="name" v-on:input="updateSearch($event.target.value)"> ' ,
  props: ['name'],
  methods: {
    updateSearch: function(value) {
      this.$emit('input', value);
    }
  }
});


const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: ''
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.9/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  
  Child: <greeting v-model="name"></greeting>
  <br><br><br>
  Main: <input type="text" v-model="name" placeholder="" />

</div>
```

I want to update both input boxes if the user enters text in either of them. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: If you pass in a reference like an object as prop, you can bind a property of that object on both your parent and child

Comment: Sorry. I did not get you. could you please provide an example?

Comment: not sure if this is what you want https://jsfiddle.net/dumz8vxf/

Comment: @ChrisLi Yes. exactly. Thank you so much. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass in a reference like an object as prop, you can bind a property of that object on both your parent and child

```js
Vue.component('greeting', {
  template: '<input type="text" v-model="name.value" />' ,
  props: ['name']
});


const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: { value: '' }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.9/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  
  Child: <greeting v-bind:name="name"></greeting>
  <br><br><br>
  Main: <input type="text" v-model="name.value" placeholder="" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually is a bad practice change props inside child component. In this case, you can create two different variables and update the other one when some of them changes it value (via events and props).

So, `greeting` component would $emit some event which you will catch inside main component and update main's `name`

On the other hand, main component would pass a prop to `greeting` which will be reactive considering changes inside main and will update variable `name` inside greeting's data.

If you get more cases like that, think about using [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you are looking for is [`.sync` modifier for events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) in Vue.js `2.3.0+`.

You can find a sample implementation of the same in my article [here](https://medium.com/@jithilmt/vue-js-2-two-way-data-binding-in-parent-and-child-components-1cd271c501ba).